# why android app crashes when socket.connect(), using 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0'?

Tags: java, android, websocket, socket.io, okhttp

I am using a standard client code to send a string to my server. I am using Socket.io with 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0' and my application is crashes when socket connect successfully with server. I am resolving this error from 3 days ago but didn't find any solution. And there is no line or library mention that does create an issue. Please help me.

This is Error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.example.leader, PID: 20246
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method callEngineGetConnection(Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Call;)Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Connection; in class 
Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/Internal; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Internal' appears in /data/app/com.example.leader-gVzHDO6ESuVvW77d1HOUUw==/base.apk:classes3.dex)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall.createWebSocket(WebSocketCall.java:154)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall.access$000(WebSocketCall.java:42)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall$1.onResponse(WebSocketCall.java:102)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:177)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Here is my Code.

```
 private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://13.251.168.7:4000/");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSocket.connect();
        mSocket.emit("authenticationCon", "hello");
        mSocket.on("unauthorization", onNewMessage);
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "response : " + data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    };
```

There is build.gradle of my project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
    // language features (either in its source code or
    // through dependencies).
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.leader"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    // (Recommended) Add Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3'

    // Add dependency
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'

    // Stripe
    implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

    implementation 'com.jcminarro:RoundKornerLayouts:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.20'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Socket.io
    implementation('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: Whatever library you're using is itself using a very ancient version of OkHttp 2.x. Getting the library to upgrade to a recent OkHttp (4.4.1 or newer) should help.

Comment: @JesseWilson sir i think this library  'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0' is using itself OkHttp, Please let me know how i upgrade OkHttp in it to recent version?

Comment: Talk to the project's maintainers! Or fork! You'll want this note on the changed web sockets API: https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/#version-350

Comment: Actually you just need to upgrade to the latest socket.io library. That should be much easier.

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Comment: @haiderali did you got the solution for this issue? I am getting same issue.

Comment: Hi @Deepak sorry for the late response, actually I just use another [socket.io library](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) instead of nkzawa and I was good to go. Thanks